# meteorjs reactjs install jest

Tags: reactjs, meteor, jestjs

I'm trying to get Jest working on my meteor/React Setup.

I've been trying to follow this tutorial:
`https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html

But after install the`npm test` and `jest` command it doesn't work.
I get the message, that jest is an unknown command.
and

```
/usr/bin/env "node": File not found
```

For `npm test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OS?

- If you didn't install NodeJs on your system - do it.
- If you already have an installation of NodeJs and you are running linux
  type `whereis node` . If you found folder like `/usr/bin/nodejs` and no `/usr/bin/node`. Just make a link like this:

  ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node